# Entity Framework 4.1 Server-side validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

The data I work with can be added from different interfaces. So in my MVC application I need to validate that the data read from the database is correct according to the rules/attribute I sat in my model. Depending on the validation send the user to different Views.

I need to do this validation on the SERVER-SIDE

```
var myModelClassObj = myDbContextInheritedModelClass.theDbSetClassMapToModel.Find(123);
// How do i validat this
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DbContext` class has a protected [ValidateEntity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.validateentity%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method. You can call that method to validate your entity.

```
public class myDbContextInheritedModelClass :  DbContext
{
     public DbEntityValidationResult Validate(object entity)
     {
         return ValidateEntity(Entry(entity));
     }
}
```

Then

```
var myModelClassObj = myDbContextInheritedModelClass
                         .theDbSetClassMapToModel.Find(123);
var validationResult = myDbContextInheritedModelClass.Validate(myModelClassObj);
```